# PHP Get AJAX Data on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I need to get a DOM element's width to work with the data later with PHP. The ajax call and the PHP is on the same page.

Here's how the page looks like:

```html
<div id="elem" width="200px"></div>

<script>
let wd = document.getElementById('elem').offsetWidth;
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "index.php", data: {"width": wd} });
</script>

<div id="elem2">
<?php
  echo $_POST['width'] . 'px';
?>
</div>
```

So I have `elem` which has a not fix width and I need to get that so I can work with that in PHP later. It is important to get the width first, because `elem` is rendered before `elem2` and I need `elem`'s width to show `elem2` properly.

The current output for `echo $_POST['width']` is nothing.
I have seen people getting the ajax data on the same page but they used form inputs, but I POST `elem`'s width.

Comment: when you run page, php run first, then ajax run, because of that you see nothing,

Comment: you can write elem1's width inside elem2 using ajax like my answer

Comment: Use `$.ajax`'s [success](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/) function to get the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this is can help you or not, but you can use success of ajax to show elem1's width inside elem2:

```
 $.ajax({
type: "post",
url: "index.php", //or somewhere else,
data: { width: wd },
dataType: "json",
success: function( response ) {
document.getElementById("elem2").innerHTML = response.width
}
})
```